# Starting of a Bluemix Application

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy one of my application in Bluemix but is getting the below error while starting the application.

Error Message :-

> **Staging...**
>   **None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application
>   Exit status 222
>   Staging failed: Exited with status 222
>   Destroying container
>   Error staging application: An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack**
>
> TIP: Use 'cf buildpacks' to see a list of supported buildpacks.
>   FAILED

---

**Update 1**

CF Command being used - `cf start application name`.

Manifest File :-

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: Creation-of-Project
  host: Creation-of-Project
  disk_quota: 1024M
  services:
  - Creation-of-Project-cloudantNoSQLDB
```

Boilerplate being used is - `cloudantNoSQLDB` service.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  What environment, node, python, ...?  What does your manifest.yml look like?  What cf command line are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I have added it to the question.  Can you now please list the exact steps you have followed so that I can attempt to reproduce the error.